# Getting report template parameter types from BIRT Engine API

Tags: java, birt

I'm rendering my BIRT reports through the provided Java engine. I use this library for that:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
    <artifactId>viewservlets</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

However, my report parameters are provided through a HTTP request, where I specify the template to be used and the report parameters too. So when I retrieve them from the URL I don't know their types anymore since they're converted to *String*, so I would like to know the types for the *scalar-parameters* in the given report template, in order to cast the parameters to their concrete type.

```
IReportRunnable runnable = engine.openReportDesign(design);
IRunAndRenderTask task = engine.createRunAndRenderTask(runnable);
task.run();
```

As I'm using this piece of code to render the report from the template, is there some way to retrieve the scalar parameter types either from `IReportRunnable` or `IRunAndRenderTask`? Since parameters are declared in the template file and being it a XML file, they would be parseable, but would be good to know if the engine API supports this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found it, it looks like a bit tricky, though. We need to create a parameter definition task over the runnable element:

```
IReportRunnable runnable = engine.openReportDesign(design);
IGetParameterDefinitionTask paramTask = engine.createGetParameterDefinitionTask(runnable);
```

Then, we access the definition through the parameter name and we can get the type value for the parameter (i.e. "string"):

```
paramTask.getParameterDefn("my_parameter_name").getHandle().getElement()
    .getProperty(null, "dataType").toString();
```

Comment: Is this still the way how to do that? Seems rather ugly to me... did you by any change find a more convenient way how to do it?